# x86 Assembly, how to reproduce fscale in C

Tags: c, assembly, floating-point, x86, reverse-engineering

Having float numbers 31.0 and 0.85842... how can I reproduce following fscale operation in C to get the same result of 1843450267.9 ?

```
(gdb) info float
  R7: Valid   0x3fff8000000000000000 +1
  R6: Valid   0x3fff8000000000000000 +1
  R5: Valid   0x4003f800000000000000 +31
=>R4: Valid   0x3ffedbc1a337fffff775 +0.8584234248846768147

(gdb) x/i $eip
0x11212 <xxx>:  fscale
(gdb) si
(gdb) info float
  R7: Valid   0x3fff8000000000000000 +1
  R6: Valid   0x3fff8000000000000000 +1
  R5: Valid   0x4003f800000000000000 +31
=>R4: Valid   0x401ddbc1a337fffff775 +1843450267.999999745
```

Comment: Thanks but it does not tell me much. If fscale doesST(0) = ST(0) * 2RoundTowardZero(ST(1)) should I do 0.8584 * (2 * 31) ?

Comment: I was just remarking on the fact that the values you show for `R4` exceed the significance for `float` type, the term you used, in fact it could be `long double` as you show 80 bits.

Comment: So it is double not a float. But how to translate it to C to get the same result?

Comment: It does not provide exactly the same functionality, but I would suggest looking at the standard math function `ldexp()`.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was looking for.

Comment: not c but c# (powershell) "{0:R20}" -f (0.8584234248846768147 * [system.math]::pow(2,[system.math]::Floor(31.2)))   , 1843450267.9999998